# How to retrieve submitted changelists in a day using Perforce Python API

Tags: python, perforce

I am new to Perforce Python API and still finding my way through it. So far I have been able to retrieve changelist information like number, desc etc, if I provide the file name. I am trying to get a list of all the submitted changelists for a specified date/time range so that I can gather information like files changed and description of each changelist etc. Is there a way to do this using the API?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't see anything obvious in the documentation. Since the API is provided by Perforce themselves, have you tried submitting a support ticket to Perforce to ask this question?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find anything in the documentation either. I haven't submitted ticket to Perforce. I am still trying to find some workarounds if not the exact thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a read of the [less than extensive P4Python documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html) and [a question from the Perforce forum](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/2848-get-submitted-files-after-given-date-time/), this code might do the trick but bear in mind it is completely untested** so caveat emptor and all that

In the filelog command, the `...` seems to be the way of requesting all files in the folder, so you only need to replace `server` and `folder` with the appropriate values.

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "1"
p4.user = "User"
p4.client = "Client"

try:
    p4.connect()
    changelist = p4.run_filelog('//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now')
    for r in changelist:
      print r.depotFile
      print r.revisions[0].time

except P4Exception:
    for e in p4.errors:
        print e

finally:
    p4.disconnect()
```

** Yes, I could have downloaded Perforce, installed it, added some files and then tested the code, but that seemed like a mild degree of overkill.

Comment: This method worked for me. I find using the API to be a little better as I have access to all the other fields and methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Following code outputs list of today's change on file.c:

```
import subprocess
import datetime
curr = datetime.datetime.now()
file = "file.c"
cmd = 'p4 changes -s submitted %s@%s/%s/%s,@now' % (file, curr.year, curr.month, curr.day)
print subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

Please note that, you should have been set P4PORT and P4USER in your environment before executing above script. If you donot want to set, you can use -p and -u switch for setting these in command.

In the above code, query is created for getting today's changelist on file.c. You can manipulate date and file name for achieving your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It helps. Although instead of a file, can this work for a folder? Changelists for all the files in a particular folder? The depot I am working with has thousands of files and it is hard to do this on a file by file basis. Making this to work on a folder basis will do the trick for me.

Comment: Yes..it can work for folder..just submit file="//mysrc/mypath/..."

Comment: Cool! I'll try this out soon and post here how it went. Does this need any additional P4 settings or installations other than the Perforce Python API?

Comment: Yes..you need perforce commandline tool and set P4USER, P4PORT in your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like:

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "A"
p4.user = "B"
p4.client = "C"

try:
    p4.connect()
    changelist = p4.run_changes('//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now')
    # p4.run("change","//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now") works as well
    for c in changelist:
      print c.desc
      # or whatever you want, including: status, client, user, changelist...

except P4Exception:
    for e in p4.errors:
        print e

finally:
    p4.disconnect()
```

To me, it feels more correct since it uses the P4Python API and the right run method (invoking the p4 change command), and you also get a lot more information about every changelist.

Chee

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -l to List the full text of description
and desc can not get by .desc
this works for me in python3

```py
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "A"
p4.user = "B"
p4.client = "C"

try:
    p4.connect()
    changelist = p4.run_changes('-l', '//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now')
    # p4.run("change","//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now") works as well
    for c in changelist:
      print(c['desc'])
      # or whatever you want, including: status, client, user, changelist...

except P4Exception:
    for e in p4.errors:
        print e

finally:
    p4.disconnect()
```