# Perforce scripting : sync whenever remote depot's files are changed

Tags: python, perforce

I have a perforce client workspace and a remote depot. I am trying to write a Python script that periodically syncs the remote depot to my client workspace whenever a new file is added or changed in that depot. I checked out P4P APIs and a very useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499535/how-to-retrieve-submitted-changelists-in-a-day-using-perforce-python-api) here and got a vague idea on how to accomplish this:-

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "1"
p4.user = "User"
p4.client = "Client"

try:
    p4.connect()
    changelist = p4.run_filelog('//server/folder/...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now')
    for r in changelist:
      print r.depotFile #does this print the contents of the changed file??
      print r.revisions[0].time #does this print the change time?

except P4Exception:
    for e in p4.errors:
        print e

finally:
    p4.disconnect()
```

If r.depotfile returns the file and its contents(equivalent to p4 print), I can use the file for further processing. Is there a way to periodically perform this operation whenever something changes in the depot? Please point me at the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what platform you're on, but all major platforms nowadays (Linux, Mac, Windows) have some notion of a "cron" or "Scheduled Tasks" feature that can run your program periodically.

For example, I used to have a website which I updated each time a new file was checked in to Perforce. I did this by having a scheduled task which ran once a minute and ran a 'sync' command. If no new files had been checked in, the sync found nothing to do (and so, did nothing); if new files had been checked in, the sync copied them to the content area of my web server.

So you can write a program, as you have, to fetch interesting files from Perforce, and then use your operating system's cron or Scheduled Tasks facility to run your program as often as you need.

Comment: That sounds interesting . I am on Windows. So I guess I will have to use some sorta windows task scheduler. By the way, how did you copy the synced files elsewhere?

Comment: Just arrange to have the Root: directory of the client workspace that you use for sync'ing be the desired target directory for your files, and that's where they will be sync'd. That is, I had a special workspace which was used for this website update task.

Comment: Windows Scheduled Tasks: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thanks. By the way, did you ever face any attributerror:logger issue when trying to run p4 sync?